# how to diff and "revert -a" added files?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am using [perforce](https://www.perforce.com/). I have added a bunch of files in a particular repository and somebody has checked in bunch of them in the same location.

Is there a perforce way of doing a `p4 revert -a` for **added** files?

The other option for me would be to copy my files to another location, sync the repo, open back the files in that repo under `p4 edit`, copy back the files and then do a `p4 revert -a`

But that is not the most ideal way.

Anyone face such a situation and know of any solution?

I am using perforce 2011.1 on linux.

Comment: What means `p4 revert -a for added files`?

Comment: if a file is opened in p4 edit and there are no changes, if i run p4 revert -a, it reverts the file. But this does not work for p4 added files

Comment: The help says:  *The -a flag reverts only files that are open for edit, add, or integrate and are unchanged or missing. Files with pending
 integration records are left open. The file arguments are optional
 when -a is specified.*

Comment: it does not revert added files, maybe because i am on an older perforce server.

Answer (score 2):

```
p4 revert -k ...
p4 sync -k ...
p4 reconcile ...
```

If you're using a version of Perforce that doesn't support `p4 reconcile` see this KB article: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3481

Comment: sorry old version of perforce, does not have reconcile

Comment: Ah, you're probably stuck with doing something a little clumsier then.  :(

Comment: Follow this KB article for the pre-reconcile equivalent of reconcile: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3481
If your version doesn't have "sync -k", use "flush".  If your version doesn't have "revert -k", I think you're stuck copying the files off since there's no other workaround for that part.